# How do I make my items in my ArrayController listen to an event from a third party API?

Tags: ember.js

I want my items in my ArrayController to listen to

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response){
  Ember.Instrumentation.instrument("facebook.like", response);
})
```

I'm making use of the a seperate itemController.

```
Like2win.ContestsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: "contest",
});
Like2win.ContestController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    instance = this;
    Ember.subscribe("facebook.like", {
      before: function(name, timestamp, payload) {
        instance.send('onLike', payload);
      },
      after: function(name, timestamp, payload) {
        //
      }
    })
  },
```

For some reason only the last item in my array ends up listening to the event. I'm just starting out with Emberjs so I expect the answer to be simple.

Answer (score 2):

`Ember.Instrumentation` is a simple software [instrumentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation_%28computer_programming%29) api. It's purpose is performance profiling, tracing, not application level event dispatching.

You can see this api in action by setting `Ember.STRUCTURED_PROFILE` to true. This will start logging the render times for all templates rendered to the DOM by ember.

The specific issue you are having deals with how the Ember `runloop` works. The `after` hooks are only fired once with the last context given. This is done to ensure that multiple property changes of the same property do not result in re-rendering the DOM that many times. So the last property change on the `runloop` wins and the DOM updates with that property value.

What you really need to do is just translate the `FB.Event` of type `edge.create` into an application event that your app understands, something like `facebookLike', similar to what you have done above.

I would do this in the `enter` hook of your `ContestRoute`. Further exiting from the `ContestRoute` should probably unsubscribe from this event. So you probably need an unsubscribe in the `exit` hook.

```
enter: function() {
  var self = this;
  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
    self.get('controller').send('facebookLike', response);
  });
}

exit: function() {
  // unsubscribe from edge.create events here
}
```

Then you can handle this event in your `ContestController` like so,

```
facebookLike: function(response) {

}
```